# Допустимы ли здесь кавычки?

Tags: кавычки

Попытки приобретения предприятий в условиях падающего рубля «за копейки», возрождение рейдерских захватов и противодействие со стороны государства, например выкуп банками с большой долей государственного участия недооцененных активов.

Answer (score 3):

Кавычки не нужны. Это устойчивое и вполне литературное выражение, если его применить рядом с глаголом ("... приобретения за копейки..."). Аналогично, лучше сблизить "выкуп недооценённых активов банками...".